# Extracting the FileName from the Path (C++ equivalent of Dephi's (System.SysUtils.ExtractFileName)

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

Using Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.4

I appreciate this question has been asked 100's of times and I have sifted through many of them.
I was looking for a Unicode method, thus not needing to convert to char const (i.e. _splitpath)
Many examples refer to using boost::filesystem, however I can't compile my (20yr old, 60+ forms and units) app to C++ 17, without spending too much time making it compliant.

I am hoping for something as simple as the Deplhi method, "ExtractFileName"

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's RTL (and VCL and FMX frameworks) is also available in C++Builder. You can literally use the same `ExtractFileName()` function in your C++ code. Simply add `#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>` to use it.

This is even pointed out in Embarcadero's documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileName